# Why can't gcc find GSL?

Tags: c, gcc, macports, gsl

I'm using a C program whose header requires GSL:

```
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
```

Not already having it, I installed it (so I believe) with MacPorts:

```
sudo port install gsl
```

Which appears to have gone swimmingly:

```
--->  Fetching archive for gsl
--->  Attempting to fetch gsl-1.16_3.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/gsl
--->  Attempting to fetch gsl-1.16_3.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/gsl
--->  Installing gsl @1.16_3
--->  Activating gsl @1.16_3
--->  Cleaning gsl
--->  Updating database of binaries
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
```

And yet GCC still doesn't know where GSL is:

```
fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_rng.h' file not found
```

What went wrong?  Is GSL just in the wrong place?

This is on OSX 10.10.2

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to specify the include path explicitly, i.e., to use something like `-I/opt/local/include/`. Also, the option `-L/opt/local/lib` will be probably necessary for linking so that the linker can find the library `libgsl`.

Comment: Some *** deleted the other answer, so let me mention here that `gsl-config --cflags` can be used to find the relevant missing flags (assuming that it is in the PATH, otherwise this just moves the problem one step further).